# I'm trying to get responses from different users

Tags: python, dictionary, user-input

I'm trying to store user responses into a list, and inserting it to each key(name), I'm not sure how to separate each list to their corresponding key. I'm aware that by appending each response to the list(movies), it adds up to 10 individual elements. If I were to make a guess, I'd have to repeat the process of asking each question, and storing the responses in a new list?

```py
favorite_movies = {}

movies = []

active = True

while active:


    name = input("What is your name? ")

    one = input("What are your top 5 favorite movies? ")
    movies.append(one)

    two = input("Movie #2- ")
    movies.append(two)

    three = input("Movie #3- ")
    movies.append(three)

    four = input("Movie #4- ")
    movies.append(four)

    five = input("Movie #5- ")
    movies.append(five)

    favorite_movies[name] = movies

    repeat = input("Enter 'quit' when finished, or 'next' to move on to the next person. ")

    if repeat == 'quit':
        active = False

    else:
        continue
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By moving the movies list inside the loop, each time the loop is run a new list is initialized

```py
favorite_movies = {}

active = True

while active:

    movies = [] # move movies list inside the loop

    name = input("What is your name? ")

    one = input("What are your top 5 favorite movies? ")
    movies.append(one)

    two = input("Movie #2- ")
    movies.append(two)

    three = input("Movie #3- ")
    movies.append(three)

    four = input("Movie #4- ")
    movies.append(four)

    five = input("Movie #5- ")
    movies.append(five)

    favorite_movies[name] = movies

    repeat = input("Enter 'quit' when finished, or 'next' to move on to the next person. ")

    if repeat == 'quit':
        active = False

    else:
        continue
```

Answer (score 1):

Move `movies = []` into the loop so you make a new list each loop. Otherwise you keep appending to the same one over and over again.